# Not able to use {{ variable }} in django-flatpages

Tags: python, django

I am using django-flatpages to allow admin to maintain / customize homepage of website from admin.

So he will able to add, edit & delete homepage div content through admin side.

But see output for following div.

Actual content added from admin side:

```
{%if user.is_authenticated %}
<h2>Welcome Back!</h2>
<div class="home-since-last">
    <div class="member-photo">
        <a href="/person/{{user.username}}"><img src="{{STATIC_URL}}{{user.get_profile.profile_image}}" alt="{{user.username}}" /></a>
    </div>
    <p><strong>Since your last visit:</strong></p>
    <ul>
    <li>+{{today_supporter_count}} supporter{{today_supporter_count|pluralize}}</li>
    <li>+{{today_comment_count}} comment{{today_comment_count|pluralize}}</li>
    <li>+{{today_adoption_count}} adoption{{today_adoption_count|pluralize}}</li>
    </ul>
    <p><a href="/you">Go to your profile &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
{% endif %)
```

Output :

```
Welcome Back!
{{user.username}}

Since your last visit:

    +{{today_supporter_count}} supporter{{today_supporter_count|pluralize}}
    +{{today_comment_count}} comment{{today_comment_count|pluralize}}
    +{{today_adoption_count}} adoption{{today_adoption_count|pluralize}}

Go to your profile »
```

Expected:

```
Welcome Back!
bhushan vaiude [Image of user]

Since your last visit:

    +12 supporters
    +4 comments
    +0 adoptions

Go to your profile »
```

As ref. to PHP, I want some thing like `include('abc.php');` so `abc.php` file can access parameters of parent or container files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should look at [django-dbtemplates](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-dbtemplates/): write your own view and let the admin change the template from the admin.

Comment: Thanks. Shared plugin helpful but I am not able to see added templates via. dbtemlates on flatpages admin page. I checked flatpage template override functionality but on flatpage admin page I am getting dropdown box for template name instead of textbox. Is m i missing anything??

Comment: Problem solved :) I removed django-flatpages-tinymce plugin. Now I am able to add flatpages & templates.